# Safari on Browserstack now working correctly

Tags: selenium, testing, browserstack

I am automating a simple login script through Browserstack using Selenium.
The script I have written works on chrome windows, chrome mac os, and Android Samsung.  However, when I run the script through apple iPhone 11 or mac os safari I get an error message saying can not locate

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Log in')]")).click();
```

Apart from the device, I am automating nothing else changes.
What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

If the test returned "cannot find element" on the device, I'll recommend changing the element locator strategy.

You could otherwise also try to inspect the app against the same browser manually via Live: https://live.browserstack.com/

This could help you narrow down if the element locator is correct.